# RecognizerIntent on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to run the following recognizer intent example that i have found in the official android developers page:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

My problem is that the activities that are extracted from the following code:
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
is always an empty list. My guess was that that a permission was missing in the manifest thus i added the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VOICE_RECOGNITION"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MIC"></uses-permission>

 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

but still with no success. The emulator is Android 2.2 on mac.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list you get back is empty that means that there are no Activities installed that handle that Intent. Try on a real device.

Comment: Hello Robby, thanks for your answer but as you can imagine this is not the best solution but rather a worst case scenario.